# Can upload form submit wait for file processing complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, forms, web2py

Can upload form submit wait for file processing complete?

I am using web2py and its sqlform to upload a video and in the meantime converting the video to flv .Both the progress of uploading and encoding is displayed by two progress-bar using this code(http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1337/upload-progress-in-web2py). The encoding begin at the backend once it detects video uploading. After the encoding and converting is both complete the user can play the converted video.

The problem is the form accepted when the upload is complete but the encoding is not complete.I tried the event.preventDefault() but the progress-bar do not display. It seems that the default submit can not be stopped at the time uploading is completed. How to prevent the submit and wait for the converting process is done and do the submit then?Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate the form without doing a database insert (see [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/7#SQLFORM-without-database-IO)). Then after validation, run a loop to continually check whether the encoding is complete, and once encoding is complete, do the database insert and return.

```
def video_upload():
    upload_form = SQLFORM(db.encodeupload)
    if upload_form.validate():
        session._unlock(response)
        [while loop checking to see if file encoding is complete]
        db.encodeupload.insert(**db.encodeupload._filter_fields(form.vars))
    [rest of code]
```

In the while loop, you might also check for errors in the encoding process and abort the insert (and return an error message) in that case.

Note, `session._unlock(response)` unlocks the session file before entering the loop -- this is necessary so the locked session file doesn't block the Ajax requests the page makes in order to update the encoding progress bar. In the controller action called by the Ajax requests, you should also add `session.forget(response)` so that action doesn't lock or write to the session.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried this and the line db.encodeupload.insert(**form.vars) occurs error:Field video_newfilename does not belong to the table.I guess the video_newfilename is the uploaded file's name after encoding(accordinglly web2py automatically obtains the original name of the uploaded file and encodes into the new filename). I didn't intervene this process. Why this error?

Comment: Sorry, form.vars has to be filtered first so it includes only fields that belong in the table -- I corrected the code above to do that. In the book, and example if this is shown [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/7#One-form-for-multiple-tables).